# Edit pdf itextsharp and send to the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I want to edit and existing pdf and to send the result to the broswer 
Here is my methode:

```
        public static byte[] Generate()
        {
        var templatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/my_template.pdf");
        // Based on:
        // http://www.johnnycode.com/blog/2010/03/05/using-a-template-to-programmatically-create-pdfs-with-c-and-itextsharp/
        var reader = new PdfReader(templatePath);
        var outStream = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outStream);

        var form = stamper.AcroFields;
        var fieldKeys = form.Fields.Keys;

        foreach (string fieldKey in fieldKeys)
        {
         if (form.GetField(fieldKey) == "MyTemplatesOriginalTextFieldA")
           form.SetField(fieldKey, "1234");
         if (form.GetField(fieldKey) == "MyTemplatesOriginalTextFieldB")
           form.SetField(fieldKey, "5678");
         }

          // "Flatten" the form so it wont be editable/usable anymore  
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;  

        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return outStream.ToArray();
        }
```

and
The method call

```
        byte[] buffer = Generate();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
```

Can someone help me in this case ?

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What's wrong with your code? Did you encounter some specific problem that you would like to ask about?

Comment: The problem is that the modified pdf is not delivered to the browser and i don't received any error from my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line

```
  byte[] buffer = Generate();
  Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
  Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
  Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=youPDFName.pdf"); 
  Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
  Response.End();
```

I have added Content-Disposition and response.end in code.

tested above code , work fine. let me know if it works you.

Comment: Unfortunelly it's still not working, i get the following response error                        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '%PDF-1.6
%����
1 0 o'

Comment: I am still getting this problem on response.                                       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '%PDF-1.6

Comment: So Download button is also inside a update panel? you need to use IFRAME in that case http://encosia.com/ajax-file-downloads-and-iframes/

Comment: yes.This maybe a solution  Many thanks .I will give you a feedback if it works.

Comment: @paritosh im unfamiliar with the buffer methods youre using but with most of them if you forget to do .flush() then the last bytes get stuck in there as it doesnt reach the limit, this could be the cause of his errors as it is an incomplete message that it cant understand